# Can you pass a variable to a Spring Flow Decision State to use as a destination?

Tags: spring, parameter-passing, spring-webflow

I have a Spring Webflow that navigates between various steps in a form in a linear fashion, both back and forwards. Due to users accessing concurrently from different browsers, it's necessary to check between each step whether the form has been completed in another browser instance. If so, the user should be skipped directly to the final page. The webflow looks roughly like this:

```
<view-state id="claimFlowStepOne" view="onlineclaims/my-claims-step1" model="submission">
    <transition on="claimStep1Continue" to="checkSubmitted1">
    </transition>
</view-state>

<decision-state id="checkSubmitted1">
    <if test="onlineClaimsAction.checkClaimAlreadySubmitted(submission.claim)"
        then="endClaimFlow" else="claimFlowStepTwo" />
</decision-state>

<view-state id="claimFlowStepTwo" view="onlineclaims/my-claims-step2"
    model="submission">
    <transition on="claimStep2Back" to="checkSubmitted2to1"
        validate="false">

    </transition>
    <transition on="claimStep2Continue" to="checkSubmitted2to3">
        <evaluate expression="onlineClaimsAction.savePaymentDetails(submission)" />
    </transition>
</view-state>

<decision-state id="checkSubmitted2to1">
    <if test="onlineClaimsAction.checkClaimAlreadySubmitted(submission.claim)"
        then="endClaimFlow" else="claimFlowStepOne" />
</decision-state>

<decision-state id="checkSubmitted2to3">
    <if test="onlineClaimsAction.checkClaimAlreadySubmitted(submission.claim)"
        then="endClaimFlow" else="claimFlowStepThree" />
</decision-state>
```

And so on, for every step. We wind up with many, many decision states (2*(N-1)) that are all very very similar.

My manager has asked that I make a common method to replace the decision states. However, neither of us know how (or if it's even possible) to make it so that we could pass one of the possible destinations as an argument. I looked through the Spring documentation but couldn't find anything about whether or not it's possible to use a variable as an action/destination. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about different options... First is that you can use [EL](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/webflow/current/reference/html/el.html) in your `flow.xml`. So you can use that in your state destinations. For instance, we have this in some of our flows:

```
    <transition on="back" to="#{flowScope.previousViewStateId}" 
                validate="false" bind="false"/>
```

Where we've placed in `flowScope` a variable named "previousViewStateId", which contains the previous state the user had visited.

But that points me to what seems like the better overall solution for you, using a custom [FlowExecutionListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/api/org/springframework/webflow/execution/FlowExecutionListenerAdapter.html). (That's how we got that "previousViewStateId" on `flowScope`, in order to use it from EL.)

With this approach, you'd check for completion in cross-cutting code. Rather than explicitly checking between each and every state in your `flow.xml`. You can extend [FlowExecutionListenerAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/api/org/springframework/webflow/execution/FlowExecutionListenerAdapter.html) and override one of the lifecycle methods to intercept and reroute under the desired condition:

> For example, one custom listener may apply security checks at the flow
>   execution level, preventing a flow from starting or a state from
>   entering if the current user does not have the necessary permissions.
>   Another listener may track flow execution navigation history to
>   support bread crumbs. Another may perform auditing, or setup and tear
>   down connections to a transactional resource.